# How to make Tikz text nodes the same height?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Iam making a quite simple draing in Tikz. I have found that I can set the with of my nodes using `text width` but `text height` doesn't work as well. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.25cm, text width=2.5cm, text height=0.25cm,
                        rectangle, draw, text centered, ]
    \node (dataset) [rectangle, draw]{Dataset};
    \node (trainingset) [rectangle, draw, below left of=dataset, node distance = 2.5 cm]{Training set};
    \node (testset) [rectangle, draw, below right of=dataset, node distance = 2.5 cm]{Test set};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The Test set box is smaller than the Training set box. Why? And how can I make them the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the `g` of *Training*. It has a `depth`, and given that you do not fix the box depth, that box will result bigger than the box with *Text set*, which has no descendant.

You can fix the depth too, adding (for exaple) `text depth=0.1cm` to obtain:

[image]